# AngularJS scope of THIS in Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, this, factory

I'm very confusing because of 'this' property.

What does "`delete this.user;`" mean in `AuthenticationFactory`. I think function "`check`" is a method so it will be bind with '`auth`' object. But, there is no '`user`' property in '`auth`' Object. Can you explain it?

Also, in '`UserAuthFactory`' (`delete AuthenticationFactory.user`, `delete AuthenticationFactory.userRole`)

I can't figure out what are "`user`" and "`userRole`" properties. There are no such properties in `AuthenticationFactory`.

Here the my code from http://thejackalofjavascript.com/architecting-a-restful-node-js-app/

```
myApp.factory('AuthenticationFactory', function($window) {
  var auth = {
    isLogged: false,
    check: function() {
      if ($window.sessionStorage.token && $window.sessionStorage.user) {
        this.isLogged = true;
      } else {
        this.isLogged = false;
        delete this.user;
      }
    }
  }

  return auth;
});

myApp.factory('UserAuthFactory', function($window, $location, $http, AuthenticationFactory) {
  return {
    login: function(username, password) {
      return $http.post('http://localhost:3000/login', {
        username: username,
        password: password
      });
    },
    logout: function() {

      if (AuthenticationFactory.isLogged) {

        AuthenticationFactory.isLogged = false;
        delete AuthenticationFactory.user;
        delete AuthenticationFactory.userRole;

        delete $window.sessionStorage.token;
        delete $window.sessionStorage.user;
        delete $window.sessionStorage.userRole;

        $location.path("/login");
      }

    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look further down, to the controller code:

```
$scope.login = function() {

  var username = $scope.user.username,
    password = $scope.user.password;

  if (username !== undefined && password !== undefined) {
    UserAuthFactory.login(username, password).success(function(data) {

      AuthenticationFactory.isLogged = true;
      AuthenticationFactory.user = data.user.username;
      AuthenticationFactory.userRole = data.user.role;

      $window.sessionStorage.token = data.token;
      $window.sessionStorage.user = data.user.username; // to fetch the user details on refresh
      $window.sessionStorage.userRole = data.user.role; // to fetch the user details on refresh

      $location.path("/");

    }).error(function(status) {
      alert('Oops something went wrong!');
    });
  } else {
    alert('Invalid credentials');
  }

};
```

On a successfully login, the controller is adding the properties `user` and `userRole` to the AuthenticationFactory.